# Correct usage of "was" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is this grammatically correct? Specifically, have I used the word “was” correctly?

> ***Was*** the second appearance of John ***was*** also in Simon's dream?

If no, how can I rewrite it correctly?

Comment: The second **was** is ungrammatical. Omit it.

Comment: We close requests for proofreading here on ELL unless a source of concern is clearly identified. You’ve asked about something specific in the question’s title, but, in the future, I recommend trying to clarify as much as you can in the body of the question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not grammatically correct.

Starting from the statement divided into subject, verb and complement

> [The second appearance of John] [was] [also in Simon's dream].

Then inverting the subject and verb to make a question (since "was" is form of "be")

> Was the second appearance of John also in Simon's dream?

This is a grammatically correct question.